# Codeigniter send mail is slow

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, sendmail

When I try to send mails with codeigniter with an ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../formularios/mail/sendmail",
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
        data: { mail: mail,
            name: name,
            province_id : province_id,
            razon_social : r_social,
            from : from,
            },
        success: function (response)
        {   
            var val = new String(response);
            //array=val.split('Error');
            pat=/Error/;
            if(pat.test(val))
                return_value =false;
        }

    });
```

I also tried every method i found on web, async :true, ajaxstart, set time out, nothing.
That responds too slow and my UI get locked, so users get crazy.
No error : http://prntscr.com/1c8ekz

**EDIT**:

well i just found that send mails take 2 seconds for mail. :(

Comment: Do you have an example that we can look at? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no error, just slow http://prntscr.com/1c8ekz

Comment: could you show the CI script you use to send mails, the one that's behind `formularios/mail/sendmail`